# How can i draw the point in the pictureBox1 center + 10 using Random?

Tags: c#

I have this simple code each time i click the button its drawing a point in the pictureBox1 at location 100,100

But i want to calculate first ( i need to learn how to do it ) the center of the pictureBox1.

Then i want to use the Random so each time i click the button it will draw a point randomaly from the pictureBox1 center location + 10

```
private void button5_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            drawPoint(100, 100);
        }

        public void drawPoint(int x, int y)
        {
         Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
         SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen);
         Point dPoint = new Point(x, (pictureBox1.Height - y));
         dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 2;
         dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 2;
         Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(4, 4));
         g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
         g.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: What will happen when you minimize and then restore the form?  Or when you drag the window of another program across your form?  Also, you need to dispose your SolidBrush

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It will calculate random offset from the centre by +10 -10

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var halfX = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Width / 2;
            var halfY = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle.Height / 2;

            Random rnd = new Random();
            var offsetX = rnd.Next(-10, 10);
            var offsetY = rnd.Next(-10, 10);

            drawPoint(halfX + offsetX, halfY + offsetY);
        }

        public void drawPoint(int x, int y)
        {
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LimeGreen);
            Point dPoint = new Point(x, (pictureBox1.Height - y));
            dPoint.X = dPoint.X - 2;
            dPoint.Y = dPoint.Y - 2;
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(dPoint, new Size(4, 4));
            g.FillRectangle(brush, rect);
            g.Dispose();
        }
     }
```

[image: Result]

Comment: StaWho almost its drawing the points in the pictureBox1 Top not in the center. some points even i cant see they are drawn over the pictureBox top not outbound on the Form but over the pictureBox top.

Comment: strange, it works for me no problem. Post updated with full app listing, have a look if you're not doing anything else that could affect drawing location

Comment: its working something else in mt form1 wasnt ok i tried your code in a new project and its working perfect. Thanks.